# if str_contains will always return else option even if it contains a certain string

Tags: php, php-8

I'm designing a word filter, I just converted over to PHP 8 so I could use str_contains and many of its new features.

When using str_contains in an if statement, if I add an else statement it always returns the else statement even if it contains the specified word.

What may be going wrong with the following code?

```php
    
function ReplaceFilter ($string) {
    // Stops people from being able to use spaces to bypass the filter.
    $string = $this->ClearSpaces($string);

    // Replace numbers that could be used to bypass with letters.
    $string_final = str_ireplace('1', 'i', $string);

    foreach ($this->banned_words as $banned_word) 
    {
        if (str_contains($string_final, $banned_word)) {
          // Repeat the replacement for the length of the banned word.
          $this->replacement = str_repeat($this->replacement, strlen($banned_word));

          // Return the result
          return str_ireplace($banned_word, $this->replacement, $string_final);
      } else {
          return $string;
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: You always `return` in either part of the `if` `else`, so it will not go through the loop, just check the first word.

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? It should not be too hard to debug this, even using `var_dump`, to see where this goes wrong

Comment: Hi Nico! I've already resolved the issue.